# Waiting of Semaphores in the pthread API

Tags: pthreads, semaphore

If a semaphore value is 0 and you wait on it, I always thought that the thread blocks.
Why doesn't the following code block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sA;

void* funcA(void* param) {
  sem_wait(&sA);
  printf("Thread A\n");
  pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() {
  sem_init(&sA, 0, 0);
  pthread_t tA;
  pthread_create(&tA, NULL, funcA, NULL);
  pthread_exit(0);
  sem_destroy(&sA);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)". If that helps.

Comment: BTW, any code after `pthread_exit()` is dead code. That function does not return.

Answer (score 1):

From man sem_destroy:

```
   Destroying  a  semaphore  that other processes or threads are currently
   blocked on (in sem_wait(3)) produces undefined behavior.
```

Looks like your implementation and mine take a different choice for how to handle this undefined behaviour. Anything goes though.

Comment: Right! But pthread_exit in main() blocks till the ThreadA completes.

Comment: `pthread_exit` won't block like that that, it just terminates the thread. `pthread_join` will block until the other thread completes *if* it's created so as to be joinable. @Mat has a good point though that the `sem_destory` call will never get hit though.

Comment: oh...I see. Learnt something. You are correct the sem_destroy is never called so I don't see that being the problem. Is the thread being blocked on your machines?

Comment: Yup, it's blocking here. I can't really do much beyond speculate right now though. I'll have a bit more of a think

Comment: @userccd - Is there *any* reason why `pthread_exit` might not be getting called on your system? The behaviour you describe is what I'd expect to see if it wasn't. Does `pthread_join` behave as expected here?

Comment: I did comment out the line sem_destroy(), still does not block. pthread_join does behave as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3155/discussion-between-usercccd-and-awoodland)